# Maven: Get artifact list of sub modules

Tags: maven

I have a root parent maven module which has lot of sub-modules that build jar files as artifacts.
I cannot change all sub-module pom.xml files.

From the root parent pom.xml is there a way I can get a list of all jars (artifacts) built by sub-modules?
Preferably after the package phase is complete?

PS: As a part of root module build I want to generate a report using a tool which requires this list of jar files.

Comment: Hey, Pune! I was there years ago for a month.

Answer (score -1):

There's a `target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/createdFiles.lst` in a Maven project.

You can use the [GMavenPlus Plugin](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) and [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) to gather these files and put their content where you want.

Another option is to [develop an own Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html) that does the same.

Comment: Thanks Gerold.
Can i get output artifact path(i.e. jar file path) for each module?
List of class files doesnt work for me.

Also is there a way i could run some commands after all submodules have been tested?

Comment: @ArpitJain I'm sorry, I missed your comment somehow in the past. I just recognized it due to a downvote now (which,BTW, I cannot comprehend). See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM for `${build.directory}` and `${build.finalName}`. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference and bind a plugin that runs the commands to a phase after the `test` phase, e.g. `prepare-package`.